# Getting string out of regex () does not behave as expected

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am currently working on a project where I need to match specific html tags and replace them by some others.

I am using Javascript in order to do so, and the code looks like :

```js
// html to update
html = '<div class="page-embed"><article><iframe src="https://alink" width="100%"></iframe></article></div>';

// regex that will match the specific "<div class="page-embed">...<iframe src="https://alink"></iframe>...</div>
 const regexIframeInsideDiv = /<\s*div\s*class="page-embed"[^>]*>.*?<\s*iframe[^>]*\s*src="(.*?)"\s*><\s*\/\s*iframe\s*>.*?<\s*\/\s*div\s*>/g;

html = html.replace(regexIframeInsideDiv, (_match, src) => {
      console.log(src);
      return `<oembed>${src}</oembed>`;
});
```

I use the () tool to get what is inside the source attribute as follow :

```js
src="(.*?)"
```

Here is the problem :

If I run the code, the console will log :

```
https://alink" width="100%
```

where it should log :

```
https://alink
```

I might be missing something, like escape string or an error anything else.. but I don't know what.

Here is the expected behaviour :https://regexr.com/4tbj6

Thank you !

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is notoriously difficult; there is [a famous humorous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/157957) advising to never attempt it. That doesn't mean there's no answer to your particular question, but it's a good idea to think about the future direction of your code, and whether a non-regex approach will be more suitable in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex, on the part you are matching src, it's not `\s*` but `\s.*`

```
src="(.*?)"\s.*>
```

```js
// html to update
html = '<div class="page-embed"><article><iframe src="https://alink" width="100%"></iframe></article></div>';

// regex that will match the specific "<div class="page-embed">...<iframe src="https://alink"></iframe>...</div>
const regexIframeInsideDiv = /<\s*div\s*class="page-embed"[^>]*>.*?<\s*iframe[^>]*\s*src="(.*?)"\s.*><\s*\/\s*iframe\s*>.*?<\s*\/\s*div\s*>/g;

html = html.replace(regexIframeInsideDiv, (_match, src) => {
  console.log(src);
  return `<oembed>${src}</oembed>`;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine now. Could you maybe explain how this was working on regexr but not with JS ?

Comment: It didn't, try using the whole regex on the `Expression` input, then go to the `Details` menu at the bottom/right (in Tools). you will see that the match are the same as in javascript. The problem was not about `src="(.*?)"` but what was after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx:

```
(?<=(<div class="page-embed".+iframe src="))(.*?)(?=")
```

Which searches for a String between `src="` and the next `"` in a div with your class and an iframe.